# Next.js useEffect is not working when use next dev execute

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I use script `next dev`, all of useEffect are not executed.
But use `next build` and then `next start` is working.
Do anybody have solution?
My next.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  modularizeImports: {
    '@mui/icons-material': {
      transform: '@mui/icons-material/{{member}}',
    },
  },
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'source.unsplash.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/random',
      },
    ],
    domains: ['fakeimg.pl'],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: Add the code to the question, of the components where the `useEffect` is not getting called.